# Error From Passing std::string Reference

Tags: c++, stl

This is probably really simple and I'm just being an idiot.

When I try to compile (Linux, 64bit, gcc) this:

```
namespace GUI {

class Manager
{
...
    private:
        bool AddElement(const std::string&, Element*);

        /// Friend functions
        friend void Element::AddToManager(const std::string&);
};

class Element
{
...
    private:
        void AddToManager(const std::string&);
        Manager* mGuiManager;
...
}

void Element::AddToManager(const std::string& rName)
{
    mGuiManager->AddElement(rName, this); // Error on this line
}

}
```

I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `GUI::Manager::AddElement(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, GUI::Element*)'
```

Where should I start to resolve this?

Comment: Have you defined your AddElement in **GUI** namespace

Comment: Everything I've done is in the GUI namespace. I put it in the post on the off-chance there's a quirk related to it.

Comment: Care to include the definition for `AddElement`?

Comment: I feel dumb now. I got distracted by the STL gibberish and forgot that "undefined reference" meant that I had commented out the actual function.

I'm new to Stack Overflow; should I delete this question or leave it up to warn others of my stupidity?

Comment: Leave it up, move your comment to an answer (answer your own question) and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Anyone who's never made a silly mistake like this, cast the first stone :)

Answer (score 0):

I was distracted by the STL bits in the error and forgot I had commented out the actual function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the following declaration to your Element class:

```
friend class Manager;
```